# Windows Service: Error related to gusvc and gupdate

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-services, service

I have a windows service which `OnStart` calls a Webservice and this webservice in turn updates the database.

I know that the webservice is works properly.

Problem is that windows service starts properly but after some time it shows errors as shown below:

[image]

and

[image]

What could be wrong?

Where exactly the problem could be?

Comment: Attach debugger to the 'gusvc' service process, extract exception text and call stack from the failure. Then add this information to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to debug.  I do not know, if this gives you a clue, but I think this is not a bad starting point.  To learn how to debug, refer to

[How to: Debug Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That is not an answer, it is a general advice.